# implement length in r5rs scheme (drracket)

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, r5rs

Is it possible to implement the R5RS scheme function "length" using the car and cdr family of functions?
If so could someone post the implementation?

Thanks,

Comment: You can also implement it using `foldr` or `reduce`. You may want to look that up if you feel like doing some extra learning >.>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it's pretty simple. I'm not giving a straight answer because this looks like homework and anyway it's trivial to write. Fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (length lst)
  (if <???>              ; if the list is empty
      <???>              ; return 0
      (<???>             ; otherwise add 1 and
       (length <???>)))) ; advance the recursion over the rest of the list
```

Notice that only `cdr` is used. We're not interested in the actual contents of the list, so we can ignore `car`.

Answer (score 1):

Óscar López's answer is correct. Here are two more implementations (again with the fill-in-the-blanks).

The first one is a left-fold solution (contrast with Óscar's solution, which is a right-fold one):

```
(define (length lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (count 0))
    (if <???>                   ; if the list is empty
        <???>                   ; return the count
        (loop <???> <???>))))   ; otherwise bump the count and continue down the list
```

This has the advantage of being tail-recursive, whereas the right-fold version isn't.

The second one is a tortoise-and-hare solution, which allows cyclic lists to be detected (the earlier solutions would run forever if given a cyclic list):

```
(define (length lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      0
      (let loop ((tortoise lst)
                 (hare (cdr lst))
                 (count 1))
        (cond ((eq? tortoise hare) #f)                   ; found a cycle
              ((null? hare) <???>)                       ; reached end of list
              ((null? (cdr hare)) <???>)                 ; reached end of list too
              (else (loop <???> <???> (+ count 2)))))))  ; bump the count and keep looking
```